# What are the grammar of these sentence? (an IELTS writing, Task 1)

Tags: reduced-relative-clauses

When I was reading this website "https://www.ieltsbuddy.com/ielts-task-1-map.html", I faced with some questions:

Somewhere it was written:

> 1-There have been several changes, the most noticeable **being** the increases in accommodation, the elimination of the fishing industry, and the introduction of sports facilities.

Is "**being**" the reduction of "**are**"? If so, What is the verb of "the most noticeable"?

> Turning to the present day map, it can be seen that the fishing facilities have all gone, **being replaced** by four apartments,

Should The bolded part in the last sentence not be just "**replaced**"?

NOTE: In the first comment, both of them were explained. I understood the second, but could one tell me more about the first sentence? Frankly, to what extent, it is not fathomable to me.

Comment: The most noticeable [of these changes] are...   The fishing facilities have gone [and have been] replaced by...

Comment: @KateBunting Could I ask you to explain more about the former one. Thanks for the second one, I learned it. Please put forward them in the answer so that I accept it.

Comment: What is a reduction?  I don't know that jargon.  What I do know is that, if you replace "being" with "are", you would be left with an independent clause and a comma splice error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"There have been several changes. The most noticeable [of these changes are/were]..."
Replacing the words in square brackets with *being* is a way of expressing the same meaning more concisely.

"The fishing facilities have gone [and have been] replaced by..." is similar.